# How to identify instances misclassified by a prediction model in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

I'm using R to build and compare several prediction models. As the test set I'm using is not "large", I'd like to go and see what instances are misclassified by which model.

An example to further explain myself. The following R code builds and tests a model for predicting the `Sex` of cats:

```
library(e1071)
library(MASS)
data(cats)

index <- 1:nrow(cats)
testindex <- sample(index, trunc(length(index)/3))
testset <- cats[testindex,]
trainset <- cats[-testindex,]

model <- svm(Sex~., data = trainset)
prediction <- predict(model, testset[,-1])

tab <- table(pred = prediction, true = testset[,1])

print(tab)
```

The code produces the following table:

```
    true
pred  F  M
   F 11  3
   M  8 26
```

How do I know exactly the 8 instances that are actually `F` but are incorrectly classified as `M`? Likewise, for the 3 instances that are actually `M` but are incorrectly classified as `F`? 
More specifically, the `cats` dataset contains 144 entries: Knowing the row of each misclassified instance is what I'm looking for.

Comment: `which(prediction != testset[,1])` will give you the misclassified rows of testset

Comment: Thanks! If you write it as an answer, I will accept it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
which(prediction != testset[,1])
```

will give you the misclassified rows of `testset`.